# Change ID to text in paragraph with jQuery and Replace spaces with underscores

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to take what text is in my `p` tag and make that the `p` tags parent (`div`) that ID. I would also like to add a `_` for any spaces in the `p` tag.

Example:

```
<div class="circle"><p>Apple</p></div>
<div class="circle"><p>Banana</p></div>
<div class="circle"><p>Carrot Juice</p></div>
```

to

```
<div id="Apple" class="circle"><p>Apple</p></div>
<div id="Banana" class="circle"><p>Banana</p></div>
<div id="Carrot_Juice" class="circle"><p>Carrot Juice</p></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('div.circle p').each(function() {
    $(this).parent('div').attr('id', $(this).text().replace(/ /g,'_'));
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8LzYk/1/)**

Comment: This answer replaces all spaces with underscores, just a step ahead :)

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery, use `$('div.circle p')` as your selector, and set its `parent()`'s id attribute via `.attr()`.

```
$('div.circle p').each(function() {
  // For each <p>, get the parent and set id attribute
  // to the value of the <p>'s text() (via $(this))
  // after replacing spaces with _
  $(this).parent().attr('id', $(this).text().replace(' ', '_'));
  // Edit: for global replacement, use a global regexp /\s/g
  $(this).parent().attr('id', $(this).text().replace(/\s/g, '_'));
});
```

#### jsfiddle:

[Here's a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/yBkjv/2/)

Comment: I just noticed that the second and third spaces don't get replaced by an `_` how can this be solved?

Comment: @Reuben See the addition above. Using a global regexp will replace all spaces.